# Hive Runtime Error

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, hiveql

After I created a Hive table that is connected to an HBase table, I performed an INSERT query such as:

```
CREATE TABLE hbase_test(key int,subject string,predicate string,object string)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:val1,cf1:val2,cf1:val3")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "hbase_test");

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE hbase_test select * from hbase_origin;
(hbase_orgin is a Hive table which has four colums - int key, subject string, predicate string, object string)
```

When I performed this query, I am getting a runtime error like the one below.

How can I solve this problem?

```
Status: Failed Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1441611615703_0524_1_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1441611615703_0524_1_00_000014, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"key":3713292,"subject":"<Department5.University49.edu/AssociateProfessor2/Publication10>","predicate":"<w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>","object":"<swat.cse.lehigh.edu/onto/univ-bench.owl#Publication>"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:138)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:324)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:176)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.call(TezTaskRunner.java:168)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.call(TezTaskRunner.java:163)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"key":3713292,"subject":"Department5.University49.edu/AssociateProfessor2/Publication10>","predicate":"w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>","object":"<swat.cse.lehigh.edu/onto/univ-bench.owl#Publication>"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:163)
    ... 13 more Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"key":3713292,"subject":"<Department5.University49.edu/AssociateProfessor2/Publication10>","predicate":"w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>","object":"swat.cse.lehigh.edu/onto/univ-bench.owl#Publication>"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:83)
    ... 16 more Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 2500 actions: ConnectException: 2500 times, 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.processOp(FileSinkOperator.java:723)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.processOp(TableScanOperator.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:493)
    ... 17 more Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 2500 actions: ConnectException: 2500 times, 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.makeException(AsyncProcess.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.access$1700(AsyncProcess.java:204)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.waitForAllPreviousOpsAndReset(AsyncProcess.java:1597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.backgroundFlushCommits(HTable.java:1069)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.doPut(HTable.java:1041)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.put(HTable.java:999)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HiveHBaseTableOutputFormat$MyRecordWriter.write(HiveHBaseTableOutputFormat.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HiveHBaseTableOutputFormat$MyRecordWriter.write(HiveHBaseTableOutputFormat.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HivePassThroughRecordWriter.write(HivePassThroughRecordWriter.java:40)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.processOp(FileSinkOperator.java:689)
    ... 23 more
```